# what are other alternative methods available for ChainMapper and ChainReducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, cloudera

I'm trying to create a sequence of MapReduce jobs in order to achieve my requirement? I heard that ChainMapper and ChainReducer would be one of the option.

However, we are looking for alternative methods required for ChainMapper and ChainReducer.
Please throw your light on me.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives you might want to look at:

- The [JobControl](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/jobcontrol/JobControl.html) class - *"This class encapsulates a set of MapReduce jobs and its dependency"*
- Apache [OOZIE](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/) - *"Oozie is a workflow/coordination system to manage Apache Hadoop(TM) jobs."*